# Помогите запустить MySQL на Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, сервер

Здравствуйте прописал в терминале:
1)`sudo apt update`
2)`sudo apt install mysql-server`
Вот что выводит:

````
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-07-12 14:05:06 UTC; 1min 21
Process: 6753 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exit

июл 12 14:05:06 ubuntu systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=e
июл 12 14:05:06 ubuntu systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'
июл 12 14:05:06 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
июл 12 14:05:06 ubuntu systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, sc
июл 12 14:05:06 ubuntu systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart
июл 12 14:05:06 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
июл 12 14:05:06 ubuntu systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too qui
июл 12 14:05:06 ubuntu systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'
июл 12 14:05:06 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
lines 1-14/14 (END)```
````

Comment: Читайте логи `journalctl -u mysql`

Comment: пишет:1)```ubuntu mysql-systemd-start[6627]: mysqld: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)``` 2)```ubuntu mysql-systemd-start[6627]: mysqld: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted.```

Comment: ну так установите владельцем этого каталога того пользователя, от имени которого должен работать mysqld. или снесите эту любительскую поделку от недоучек из oracle и поставьте нормальный mariadb.

Comment: Просто хотелось попрактиковаться именно с MySQL)

Comment: я прописываю ```chmod 777 /etc/mysql/conf.d/``` нет никаких изменений(

Comment: @Roman владелец меняется командой `chown user:group /path/file` так же ключ `-R` для указания рекурсивного изменения владельца. Верните права на файлы в изначальный вид и просто поменяйте владельца, на того от чьего имени запускаете MySQL

Comment: я прописываю 1)```sudo groupadd groupname``` 2) ```sudo gpasswd -a root groupname```
3)```sudo chown -R root:groupname /etc/mysql/conf.d/```
4)```sudo chmod 777 /etc/mysql/conf.d/``` но нет изменений(

Comment: я запускаю MySQL так: root@ubuntu:~# sudo service mysql status

Comment: Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-07-12 14:05:06 UTC; 1min 21
Process: 6753 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exit
________________________________________________________________________________sudo service mysql restart
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: во-первых, запуск это `service mysql start`, во-вторых, `ROOT@ubuntu:~#` и `SUDO` зачем?

Comment: я это понимаю, но у меня всё равно не запускается(

Comment: Удалось запустить MySQL, установив Ubuntu 14.04.